# Creating rest api with get method using AWS amplify, with a python lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-amplify-cli, aws-rest-api

Is there a way to set up a rest api using a python lambda function with a get method that uses query parameters by using the amplify CLI or editing the code?

I know this can be done through the AWS Management Console, but was hoping for a more code-oriented solution. Below is the sample lambda I'm trying to use and a simple example of how I would like to get different api responses (length of dummy text string) based on the get method called by the api using something like "curl https://......../myapi?length=4"

```
import json

def handler(event, context):
  print('received event:')

  str_len = event['queryStringParameters']['length']

  body = {
    "message" : "DUMMY TEST"[1:str_len]
    }

  response = {
    "statusCode" : 200,
    "body" : json.dumps(body),
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  return response
```